# Normal Bake Artifacts

Tags: uv, artifacts

As the title states I get weird artifacts. The artifacts are on the low poly model after the high poly bake onto the low poly model. The object (horns) have holes in them that will be covered up by a second set of horns (as you can see in the both horns picture). The UV map appears to be fine (blue with little to no green areas, when you zoom in on the map) to my knowledge, but is very dense in some areas, don't think that's the issue but maybe it is? The normal bake map doesn't look the prettiest but I don't understand that to be the issue? I also used a cage for the bake which I believe to be good? Please help me :( and I appreciate all the help :D

**BAKED MODEL WITH ARTIFACTS**
[image]

**UV MAP**
[image]

**NORMAL BAKE MAP**
[image]

**CAGE**
[image]

**BOTH HORNS**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by changing the bake to non-color :)